# Recorrer columna en DataGridView y Sumar C#

Tags: c#

Que tal, espero y me puedan ayudar.
Tengo un datagridview, los datos los cargo mediante un archivo txt, con dos campos (Código y Stock).

Ahora bien, como le hago para que a la hora de recorrer la columna Código al encontrar algún código repetido me sume el STOCK de las dos o n códigos encontrados.

El resultado solo seria un código y su debido STOCK actualizado de los n códigos
Ayuda!

Comment: Añade algo de código del que poder partir. Sería útil saber si usas algún tipo de colección antes de pasar los datos obtenidos al datagridview.

Comment: dataGridView2.DataSource = ConvertToDataTable(" ", 2);
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; i++)
{
// y ya no se que hacer  
}

Answer (score 1):

lo que yo haria, si son solo eso 2 campos, es cargar los datos del txt en una lista generica KeyValuePair.

ejemplo

```
        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"c:\stock.txt");
        string line = String.Empty;
        var contenido = file.ReadToEnd();
        file.Close();
        var list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
        var dividir = contenido.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None);
        foreach (var d in dividir)
        {
            var s = d.Split('\t');
            list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(s[0], int.Parse(s[1])));
        }
        list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("SUMA TOTAL", (from l in list select l.Value).Sum()));

        dgstock.DataSource = list;
```

[image: captura]

[KeyValuePair](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42(v=vs.110).aspx)

espero que te sirva

UPDATE 2/6/2017

```
public partial class Test2 : Form
{
    public List<stock> ListaStock { get; set; }
    public Test2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Cargar();
    }
    private void Cargar()
    {
        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"c:\stock.txt");
        string line = String.Empty;
        var contenido = file.ReadToEnd();
        file.Close();
        if (ListaStock != null)
            ListaStock.Clear();
        else
            ListaStock = new List<stock>();
        var dividir = contenido.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        foreach (var d in dividir)
        {
            var s = d.Split('\t');
            ListaStock.Add(new stock() { Codigo = s[0], Cantidad = int.Parse(s[1])});
        }
        dgvData.DataSource = ListaStock;
    }
    public class stock
    {
        public string Codigo { get; set; }
        public int Cantidad { get; set; }
    }

    private void btnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Cargar();
    }

    private void btnBuscar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtBuscar.Text == String.Empty)
            return;
        dgvData.DataSource = null;
        var result = (from c in ListaStock where c.Codigo == (String)txtBuscar.Text select c).ToList<stock>();
        var suma = (from s in result select s.Cantidad).Sum();
        result.Add(new stock() { Codigo = "SUMA TOTAL", Cantidad = suma });
        dgvData.DataSource = result;
    }
}
```

[image: Captura 1]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: lo que pasa es que no quiero sacar la suma total ... quiero recorrer toda la columna KEY validar datos, si hay códigos repetidos, sumar (VALUE) de esos datos repetidos. Y no se como hacerle. Ya hago el recorrido pero no se como validar y sumar.

Comment: por lo que entiendo. queres tenes cargado el datagridview y después aplicar filtros para buscar los códigos repetidos y sumarsu stock. si me confirmas te coloco un ejemplo.

Comment: Exacto, eso es con lo que estoy batallando ...

Comment: OK, ahí hice un update

Comment: Bueno no tengo que buscar el código y tampoco tengo que tener una columna de SUMA Total, la suma la tiene que hacer en la primera celda de STOCK del código correspondiente. Pero muchísimas gracias, me has ayudado demasiado, Un abrazo.